# Are there any efforts to measure the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter?

Tags: experimental-physics, curvature, geometry

There is a mathematical constant $\pi$ that is known to a gazillion decimal places.  Based on the usual axioms of geometry this value is coincident with the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter.  Are there any large-scale experiments to confirm the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter?

For example, there [have been many experiments](https://scienceready.com.au/pages/determination-of-speed-of-light) to measure the speed of light in a vacuum $c$.  There are ongoing experimental efforts to measure $c$ with ever increasing precision.  Are there similar efforts focused on measuring the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter and comparing this to the computed values for $\pi$?

Comment: +1  This is a perfectly valid question.  It's a measurement that can in principle be made -- and the answer is that, if your measurement is found to deviate from the theoretical value, it's because space is curved!  If $\pi$ is smaller than expected, space is curved like the surface of a sphere; if $\pi$ is greater than expected, space is curved like a saddle or potato chip.  Of course, general relativity says that space *is* curved, as is spacetime on the whole.  But the effect on what you would measure for $\pi$ is insanely small, except in the most extremely curved regions of spacetime.

Comment: However, the ratio of circumference to (geodesic) diameter is not actually called $\pi$ in curved space.  The symbol $\pi$ is really reserved for the value of that ratio in flat space only, afaik.

Comment: At some level, you can think of the precision tests of general relativity by satellites as performing just this kind of measurement. And they do find a deviation because of the spatial curvature from Earth, in agreement with the prediction of relativity.

Comment: And by the way: although there are various ways to describe curvature (especially once you get to 4 dimensions), the particular notion of curvature that you are referring to is called "[sectional curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectional_curvature)".  It is basically the curvature of 2D slices of space(-time), and if you know the sectional curvatures of all 2D slices, then you can derive everything about the curvature of space(-time).

Comment: @AdamHerbst "The symbol $\pi$ is really reserved for the value of that ratio in flat space only." Do you mean to say that the phrase "space is flat at this location" is defined as "The ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter can be measured to be equal to the value $\sqrt{ 6 \sum 1/n^2 }$ at this location"?

Comment: @AdamHerbst perhaps adding a "in this plane" or some such qualifier, since there are many ways to curve space in 4d.

Comment: Yes, that can essentially work.  You may also have heard that space is **always** "locally" flat.  This means, if we call your ratio $f(r)$ as a function of (geodesic) radius, we can say $f'(0) = 0$ at every point and in every plane.  So it is really $f''(0)$ that corresponds to local curvature.  If that is zero, then you can say space is flat at that point.

Comment: Gauss experimentally measured the value of $\pi$ by using surveying techniques to measure the sum of the angles of a triangle with vertices at mountain peaks located roughly 100km apart.  It seems to be unclear whether his primary purpose in this experiment was to verify the value of $\pi$.   Not long afterward, Lobachevski designed an experiment specifically designed to test the value of $\pi$ using a triangle with vertices at Sirius and the two locations of the earth six months apart.  If the question is open, I will post this as an answer, with more details.

Comment: I should add that "measuring the value of $\pi$" is a poor way to phrase this, because the value of $\pi$ is, by definition, a definite integral of the arctangent function, and its value is fixed by that definition just as surely as the value of the number 7 is.  You are writing $\pi$ to mean something like "the ratio of the circumference to the diameter of a physical circle" or "the sum of the angles of a physical triangle".   It would be better to use some symbol other than $\pi$ to represent that thing, but in my comment above I stuck with your notation.

Comment: And of course, with that definition, the value of $\pi$ will of course depend on *which* physical circle or physical triangle you have in mind.

Comment: @WillO I don't think many people use Weierstrass' definition of $\pi$ anymore.  To be sure, though, with any sort of vanilla set of axioms for a mathematics, one could define a constant $\pi$ in any number of equivalent ways.  One such way is in a comment of mine above.

Comment: @WillO if you think the community would be more receptive to the question with an alternate phrasing, I'm happy to make changes.

Comment: @Him:  Of course you are free to define $\pi$ in any of many equivalent ways, and logically it doesn't matter which you choose.  But it strikes me as quite odd and unmotivated to define it via the $\zeta$-function, because the fact that $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ comes as a surprise to just about everybody who sees it for the first time, which means that most people already have a definition of $\pi$ in mind before they become aware of this equality.

Comment: @him :  If you are revising, I would delete any mention of "measuring $\pi$", which makes as much sense as "measuring 137" and could easily turn people off.  (It almost made me stop reading, for one.)  Just  ask about what you mean to ask about, i.e. measuring the ratio of the circumference to the diameter of a physical circle and testing the hypothesis that it is equal to $\pi$.  I'd also drop the weird phrase "theoretical value"  which seems to mean the same thing as"value".

Comment: @Ghoster it seems that you are also displeased with the phrasing of the question.  If you have a better suggestion, I am amenable.  Until one takes a calculus course, the constant $\pi$ is defined as "the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter".  I'm finding it somewhat amusing that a question whose meaning would be obvious to any adolescent is being derided as meaningless by the congnoscente.  :)

Comment: @WillO "measuring 137" This seems sane enough to me, although I should think it has been experimented with enough by ordinary people in their everyday lives.  I don't see any a priori reason why the usual axioms of geometry or of natural numbers would accurately describe our universe.  The statement "The axioms of Euclidean geometry apply in our universe" is a physical theory, and there is an associated value of $\pi$ predicted by the theory that would apply in our universe if the theory is correct.

Comment: I suppose you could use something like $\pi_p$ to denote physical $\pi$, the value of which varies everywhere, and depends on how you choose to define it.

Comment: @PM2Ring I feel like I have done just that in the question?  Folks complained that I was not clear about my use of  $\pi$, so I have attempted to distinguish between 1) "the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter" as that phrase is meant in Euclidean Geometry (this value is exactly the theoretical $\pi$ that we know and love) and 2) "the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter" as that phrase is meant w.r.t. actual points in the actual space that we live in.

Comment: @PM2Ring Since the phrase is identical in the world of math and the world of experimental physics, I don't know of an easy way to disentangle the two concepts.  One is "theoretical", but others complained about my use of that word.

Comment: @PM2Ring indeed, if you check the edit history, my original question was basically "does anyone measure pi" and was very succinct.  It was insisted by other parties that all of the distinction between physics and "pure math" be brought into the question.  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142944/discussion-between-pm-2ring-and-him).

Comment: This question reminds me (in a good way) of [my favorite April-Fools physics paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5321).